# Adding some noise to dataset in K Neighbors Classifier using sklearn.utils.shuffle

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to add some noise to the training dataset to monitor the performance of my ML algorithm. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

X_shuffled,y_shuffled = shuffle(X_train, y_train, random_state=0, n_samples=50)
X_noisy=np.concatenate((X_train, X_shuffled))
y_noisy=np.concatenate((y_train, y_shuffled))

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5)
knn.fit(X_noisy, y_noisy)

print('accuracy: ', knn.score(X_test, y_test))
```

But the problem is the accuracy of my model after adding noise is the same as the accuracy before adding some noise. I do not why?
I also tried to add some noise using sklearn.utils.resample but the accuracy was the same again.
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With **shuffle** your not really adding noise just more data. I took iris data as benchmark,

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris() # load data
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)
```

Small set

```
XX = X_train[1:4,:]
YY = y_train[1:4][:,None]
XY = np.concatenate((XX, YY), axis=1)
array([[5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1, 1. ],
       [5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8, 1. ],
       [5.8, 2.8, 5.1, 2.4, 2. ]])
```

Now shuffle

```
XXs, YYs = shuffle(XX, YY, random_state=0)
XY = np.concatenate((XX, YY), axis=1)
array([[5.8, 2.8, 5.1, 2.4, 2. ],
       [5.9, 3.2, 4.8, 1.8, 1. ],
       [5.5, 2.4, 3.8, 1.1, 1. ]])
```

One can see the input rows X[I,:] map to the same Y label. So the code is adding more data simply.
So running with "noise" (read more data), should give higher accuracy here,

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris() # load data
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30)
X_shuffled,y_shuffled = shuffle(X_train, y_train, random_state=0)

X_noisy=np.concatenate((X_train, X_shuffled))
y_noisy=np.concatenate((y_train, y_shuffled))

model = make_pipeline( StandardScaler(), KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 5) )

model.fit(X_noisy, y_noisy)

print('accuracy with "noise": ',  model.score(X_test, y_test))
```

```
accuracy with "noice":  0.9777
```

And running with

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Gives,

```
accuracy with "noise":  0.9333
```

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation but it does not answer my question. My question is how can I add some noise to my training dataset. I think the accuracy of the model should decrease in presence of some noise but the result does not show this.